# How does SQL determine uniqueness for a multi column unique index

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing the sequences of Addresses in a delivery route, eg.:

| AddressId | RouteId | Sequence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | 1 | 11 |
| 46 | 11 | 1 |

I have a joint unique index on `RouteId` and `Sequence`.
Would the above table violate that as both records combine to `111` or is the index smart enough to realize this is no duplicate?

Comment: Smartness is not required - they clearly aren't duplicates.

Comment: Smartness is subjective.

Comment: @YStroli what did you try?

Answer (score 5):

The unique index does not concatenate the two values in the way you suggest, it ensures that `{RouteId,Sequence}` pairs are unique.

In your example, the pairs are `{1,11}` and `{11,1}` which are different and therefore are both legal in the index. If you tried to add a third row with routeId =1 and Sequence =11, it would violate the unique index